# why doesn't my added dir show in $PATH?

Tags: paths

I am trying to use ocelotgui which is a tool to debug SQL stored procedures. The instructs say to make sure that the path to libQt*.so appears in the $PATH. I researched how to add that to my $PATH and was told to add the last line in my .profile to point at the dir where my libQt5Gui.so.5 appears. So I added it to .profile in the last line (as instructed)as below:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi

 export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
 export  LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I rebooted. The problem is that when I echo $PATH,the added dir doesn't show.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is that the correct user/location? are you echoing for the path from the same user?

Comment: I think so. I am running Docker on this machine and doing my development under that. But to develop and debug stored procedures, do I need to be in docker?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you downloaded the most recent version of ocelotgui from https://github.com/ocelot-inc/ocelotgui
and you have a recent Ubuntu version so libQt5Gui.so* exists, e.g. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5.9.
And you installed the "Debian-like, Qt5" package.
It seems odd that ocelotgui didn't find the Qt library, and I don't see where the current instructions recommend changing $PATH. Is this an error message when you try to start the program?
Just as a temporary experiment, if the .so file is on /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/, you could try the unusual workaround
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
or start ocelotgui with
ocelotgui --ld_run_path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu